# PowerShell Mass Test-Connection

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to put together a simple script that will check the status of a very large list of servers. in this case we'll call it servers.txt. I know with Test-Connection the minimum amount of time you can specify on the -count switch is 1. my problem with this is if you ended up having 1000 machines in the script you could expect a 1000 second delay in returning the results. My Question: Is there a way to test a very large list of machines against test-connection in a speedy fashion, without waiting for each to fail one at a time?

current code:

```
Get-Content -path C:\Utilities\servers.txt | foreach-object {new-object psobject -property @{ComputerName=$_; Reachable=(test-connection -computername $_ -quiet -count 1)} } | ft -AutoSize
```

Comment: `Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -AsJob`

Comment: Great, So I now have them all running as Jobs. by using 

Get-Content -path C:\Utilities\servers.txt | ForEach-Object {Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -count 1 -AsJob }  | ft -AutoSize

How would I get a nice output of all my Jobs back into a AutoSized Table? Thanks.

Comment: It's a little bit more complicated, the `-AsJob` switch makes `Test-Connection` a Job, so you have to retrieve job result using `Get-Job`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Test-Connection has a -AsJob switch which does what you want. To achieve the same thing with that you can try:

`Get-Content -path C:\Utilities\servers.txt  | ForEach-Object { Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 1 -AsJob } | Get-Job | Receive-Job -Wait | Select-Object @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$_.Address}},@{Name='Reachable';Expression={if ($_.StatusCode -eq 0) { $true } else { $false }}} | ft -AutoSize`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Nice, faster than my workflow solution for what I've tested. Including the IPV4Address in the output however seems to slow things down considerably *(but still faster)*

Comment: You can avoid ForEachObject and just use result of Get-Content in parameter.
`Test-Connection -ComputerName (Get-Content -path C:\Utilities\servers.txt) -Count 1 -AsJob | Get-Job | Receive-Job -Wait | Select-Object @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$_.Address}},@{Name='Reachable';Expression={if ($_.StatusCode -eq 0) { $true } else { $false }}} | ft -AutoSize`

Answer (score 6):

I have been using workflows for that. Using jobs spawned to many child processes to be usable *(for me)*.

```
workflow Test-WFConnection {
  param(
    [string[]]$computers
  )
    foreach -parallel ($computer in $computers) {        
        Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  }
}
```

used as

```
Test-WFConnection -Computers "ip1", "ip2"
```

or alternatively, declare a `[string[]]$computers = @()`, fill it with your list and pass that to the function.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell 7 and `Foreach-Object -Parallel` makes it much simpler now:

```
Get-Content -path C:\Utilities\servers.txt | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    Test-Connection $_ -Count 1 -TimeoutSeconds 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable e
    if ($e)
    {
        [PSCustomObject]@{ Destination = $_; Status = $e.Exception.Message }
    }
} | Group-Object Destination | Select-Object Name, @{n = 'Status'; e = { $_.Group.Status } }
```