# if statement in Start-Job scriptblock

Tags: powershell, if-statement, start-job

I'm trying to create a simple network scanner using PowerShell and I want it to run multiple "pings (or in this case test-connection)" in parallel.

Start-Job seems to be the best way to accomplish this multi-threading scenario.

Here is a simplified example of what i'm trying to do.

```
$list=@("192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2", "192.168.1.3", "192.168.1.4")

ForEach ($item In $list) {
  Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    if (Test-Connection $item -Quiet -Count 1) {
      Add-Content -value "$item found" -Path C:\logs\test.txt
    }
  }
}
```

This however does nothing.
If I remove the Start-Job part it does work, but loses its multiprocessing.
If I remove the if statement the writing to file part works.

So the issue seems to be when using an if statement in a scriptblock within a job.

There must be something about the start-job command i'm missing.
Or is there any better way to create this kind of script?

Comment: Well, the first issue that I see is the potential for file lock collisions on the file you are trying to write to.

Comment: I created a script with a for loop (1-1000) that creates jobs that writes to the file and it works. so don't think that is the issue.

Comment: I'm not saying that it is the issue. I'm saying that this is a bad way to write your code. It is not thread safe. Doing it with a 1-1000 loop is not the same situation at all and is thread safe.

Comment: Well, the 1-1000 if not guarantedd to be thread safe either but it is much much less likely to generate collisions.

Comment: The issue with the Start-Job is scope. You need to pass the IP into the scriptblock

Comment: Oh, right! I'll try that. But yeah I realize this way of multithreading is kind of wonky. Any suggestion on how to ping multiple computers without waiting for an answer in a more elegant way?

Comment: Well, you can ping them this way just fine. It is just writing to the file that is the issue. Have the ping be a return from the job and have the parent thread do all the writing.

Comment: Hmm, i'm at a bit of a loss here. Could you elaborate with an example?

Comment: Well if you literally want to Test-Connect a bunch of machines then this is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30068678/powershell-mass-test-connection?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$item is not available within the scriptblock scope, so you need to pass the value in as an argument.

```
$list=@("192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2", "192.168.1.3", "192.168.1.4")

ForEach ($item In $list) {
  Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    param($item)
    if (Test-Connection $item -Quiet -Count 1) {
      Add-Content -value "$item found" -Path C:\logs\test.txt
    }
  } -argumentlist $item
}
```

Comment: Still not a good implementation due to potential file write collisions.