# PowerShell Test-Connection -efficient Method

Tags: powershell

One Bronze medal = Newbi , have scoured this site for years, so a million belated thanks, once again!

Just finished up a few different PowerShell ver 5.1 scripts that perform a test-connection on the same 2000 devices regularly.

Out to a csv file

And they are all slow, some minor speed improvements when tweaking it down to the bare bones.

I’ve scaled the script to the minimal, IPADDRESS and NAME only

I’ve run a few comparison tests against a batch file (ping 123.456.789.001 >> PingTest.txt ) and these tests APPEAR to run quicker than my PS script (will run a full apple to apples test tomorrow), but confident something is amiss in the PS code.

Am looking at arrays, and how piping works, but am afraid I’m putting the cart in front of the horse, or there is something going on with how PS handles the csv format and/or ping list in its memory

My most efficient current script below,

Is the following link pointing me in the right direction,? **Specifically the asJob switch**

[PowerShell Mass Test-Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30068678/powershell-mass-test-connection)

```
$info = "" | Select IPaddress,Name
$OutputFile = new-item -itemType File -path  C:\Temp\Results.csv -force -value "IPaddress,Name`r`n" | out-null
 
Import-csv C:\Temp\GetList.csv | ForEach-Object {
if ($_.IPaddress) {
 
if (-Not (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_.IPaddress -Quiet -Count 2 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
$info.IPaddress = $_.IPaddress
$info.Name = $_.Name

add-content -value "$($info.IPaddress),$($info.Name)"  -path C:\Temp\Results.CSV
}
}
}
```

The export-csv is faster, thank you. I'm not sure if I have it in the right place, but it works, will run some tests on it tomorrow.  I may have to include the passes tests though , still getting my head around the get-job cmdlet.

```
$info = "" | Select IPaddress,Name,Status

Import-csv c:\Temp\GetList.csv | ForEach-Object {
if($_.Ipaddress) {

if (-Not(Test-Connection -ComputerName $_.IPaddress -Quiet -Count 2 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {

$info.IPaddress = $_.IPaddress
$info.Name = $_.Name
$info.Status = "Failed"
$info | export-csv C:\Temp\Results1.csv -Force -Notypeinformation -Append
}
}
}
```

```
$list = Import-Csv C:\Temp\GetList.csv
ForEach ($item In $list) {
  Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    param($item)
    if (Test-Connection -Computername $item.IPaddress -Quiet -Count 1) {
      Add-Content -value "$($item.IPaddress),$($item.Name),$($item.Stauts)" -Path C:\Temp\xlistlist.csv
      $list | Export-csv c:\Temp\xCSvreults.csv -Force -NoTypeInformation -Append
    }
  } -argumentlist $list
}
```

Thanks Santiago, I did some exploring here, just ran out of time for the day. THANK YOU you for the code examples they cleared a few things up for me :-) –
Have Computer
Dec 2 at 3:59

Would you mind adding some inline comments so I can follow along? Just trynna understand multi-threading (using runspaces) a bit better. –
Abraham Zinala
Dec 2 at 4:58
1

@AbrahamZinala is there a specific part you're struggling to understand? i'm not an expert on this and wouldn't like to give false information. Might be better to pick up all the parts you don't understand and ask a new question –
Santiago Squarzon
Dec 2 at 12:19

Nah man, sorry, I figured it out lol –
Abraham Zinala
Dec 2 at 13:43
1

@AbrahamZinala the only hard part to understand is the [powershell] instance part imo, and you can think of it as a Start-Job but much faster and less memory consuming, you add your scriptblock with .AddScript({...}) and then the parameters with .AddParameters([hashtablehere]). It's important to save the PSInstance in a variable so that we can get the output out of it and it's handler (Status = $psinstance.BeginInvoke()) to know when the instance has completed. The rest is just pure blueprint, once you have one you can copy paste it :P –
Santiago Squarzon
Dec 2 at 13:50

@HaveComputer I have no idea what your comment means. –
Santiago Squarzon
Dec 5 at 1:10
the 2 solutions presented work much faster, my code however is lacking. –
Have Computer
Dec 5 at 1:16

@HaveComputer I know that, this can perform 50x faster or even more depending on hardware and bandwidth. –
Santiago Squarzon

Comment: Yes, that link is pointing you in the right direction. What it seems like, is that you didn't consider how the actual code was being executed. Every single answer there had **some** form of *multi-threading* which it's a lot faster than a *serial* connection/loop. Also, when exporting to a CSV, you should really be using the `Export-Csv` cmdlet even if it's just adding more to it; use the `-Append` switch.

Comment: Thank you Abraham, I did rework the Export-Csv part, researching the get-job cndlet now, I posted the new code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good place where you can use [runspaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0), I would love to test if `Test-Connection -AsJob` performs better than this but for some reason it is not available on PS Core on Linux.

Code below took around 10 seconds to scan 254 IPs using my private network IP range. There is a lot of tweaking that can be done, i.e. you can poke around the `$Threshold` variable, it's currently running 100 runspaces at a time, `Count` and `TimeoutSeconds` for `Test-Connection` have been set to `2` you can tweak that too.

`$results` variable can be exported using `Export-Csv`.

```
# Change this value for tweaking
$Threshold = 100
$RunspacePool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $Threshold)
$RunspacePool.Open()

# This is for testing, use your CSV here instead
# => $list = Import-Csv C:\Temp\GetList.csv
$list = 1..254 | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        IPAddress = "192.168.1.$_"
        Hostname = "ExampleHost$_"
    }
}

$scriptBlock = {
    param($ip, $hostname)

    $params = @{
        Quiet = $true
        Count = 2
        TimeoutSeconds = 2
        ComputerName = $ip
    }

    $status = Test-Connection @params

    [pscustomobject]@{
        Hostname = $hostname
        IPAddress = $ip
        Status = ('Failed','Success')[[int]$status]
    }
}

$runspaces = foreach($line in $list)
{
    $params = @{
        ip = $line.IPAddress
        hostname = $line.Hostname
    }

    $psinstance = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($scriptBlock).AddParameters($params)
    $psinstance.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
    
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Instance = $psinstance
        Status = $psinstance.BeginInvoke()
    }
}

while($runspaces.Status.IsCompleted -contains $false)
{
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
}

$results = $runspaces.ForEach({ $_.Instance.EndInvoke($_.Status) })
$RunspacePool.Dispose()
```

**`$results` Sample:**

```
Hostname       IPAddress     Status
--------       ---------     ------
ExampleHost1   192.168.1.1   Success
ExampleHost2   192.168.1.2   Failed
ExampleHost3   192.168.1.3   Success
ExampleHost4   192.168.1.4   Failed
ExampleHost5   192.168.1.5   Success
ExampleHost6   192.168.1.6   Failed
ExampleHost7   192.168.1.7   Failed
ExampleHost8   192.168.1.8   Failed
ExampleHost9   192.168.1.9   Failed
ExampleHost10  192.168.1.10  Failed
...
...
```

Comment: Thanks Santiago, I did some exploring here, just ran out of time for the day. THANK YOU you for the code examples they cleared a few things up for me :-)

Comment: Would you mind adding some inline comments so I can follow along? Just trynna understand multi-threading (*using runspaces*) a bit better.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala is there a specific part you're struggling to understand? i'm not an expert on this and wouldn't like to give false information. Might be better to pick up all the parts you don't understand and ask a new question

Comment: Nah man, sorry, I figured it out lol

Comment: @AbrahamZinala the only hard part to understand is the `[powershell]` instance part imo, and you can think of it as a `Start-Job` but much faster and less memory consuming, you add your scriptblock with `.AddScript({...})` and then the parameters with `.AddParameters([hashtablehere])`. It's important to save the `PSInstance` in a variable so that we can get the output out of it and it's handler (`Status = $psinstance.BeginInvoke()`) to know when the instance has completed. The rest is just pure blueprint, once you have one you can copy paste it :P

Comment: @HaveComputer I have no idea what your comment means.

Comment: the 2 solutions presented work much faster, my code however is lacking.

Comment: @HaveComputer I know that, this can perform 50x faster or even more depending on hardware and bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Test-Connection -computername  (Get-Content -Path “C:\Temp\GetList.csv”) }
```

Its lacking the fundamentals, works, DE fast.

Comment: run, do, save...get